Law of Total Probability (LOTP) on a different sample space: Blitzstein - Chapter 4, exercise 7
I am self-studying the book Introduction to Probability (2e) by Joseph Blitzstein, Jessica Hwang. I was solving the exercise 7 of 4th chapter which states:
A certain small town, whose population consists of 100 families, has 30
families with 1 child, 50 families with 2 children, and 20 families with 3
children. The birth rank of one of these children is 1 if the child is the
firstborn, 2 if the child is the secondborn, and 3 if the child is the
thirdborn.
a) A random family is chosen (with equal probabilities), and then a random
child within that family is chosen with equal probabilities. Find PMF, mean,
and variance of the child's birth rank.
b) A random child is chosen in the town (with equal probabilities). Find PMF,
mean, and variance of the child's birth rank.
I unconsciously calculated probability of each X as follows for part (a) (and
then calculated mean and variance):
Let X denote birth rank and Y denote the number of children in a family,
then
P(X=k) = P(X=k and Y=1) + P(X=k and Y=2) + P(X=k and Y=3) = P(Y=1)P(X=k |
Y=1) + P(Y=2)P(X=k | Y=2) + P(Y=3)P(X=k | Y=3)
where P(Y=1) = 3/10, P(Y=2) = 5/10, P(Y=3) = 2/10 which is calculated as P(Y=y) = (the number of y-children families) / (the total number of families).
For part (b) I calculated P(X=k) as
P(X=k) = (the number of k-th born children in town) / (the number of total children in town)
When I got a different answer for the part (b) of the exercise I got
confused, since for each P(X=k) I got two different values.
So the questions is:

Is it true to condition on a different sample space? In this case, what do
we get after using the Law of Total Probability?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If I'm understanding your concern correctly, you are concerned because you're splitting up into families. But the sample space here is not the set of families, it's the set of children. So you're concerned that you're working in a different sample space.
If we switched to a new sample space where each individual outcome was a family, that would indeed be a different probability space. If I'm understanding your question correctly, this is what you think you may have done. But if we say that each family is not an outcome, but a set of outcomes (a set of each of the children in that family), then this is a perfectly correct use of the law of total probability. Because the law of total probability does not require that we partition into individual outcomes. It works when we partition into (countably many) measurable sets.
As an example, let's say we have two families. The Abel family and the Babbage family. The Abel family has two children, Carl and Dede. The Babbage family has one child, Emmy. We can look at the sample space where outcomes are children, to get $$\Omega=\{\text{Carl,Dede,Emmy}\}.$$ We could also look at the different sample space where the different outcomes are families:  $$\Omega'=\{\text{Abel,Babbage}\}.$$   We wouldn't want to apply the law of total probability to $\Omega'$ to deduce something about $\Omega$. But if instead we establish the partition $$A_\text{Abel}=\{\text{Carl,Dede}\},$$ $$A_\text{Babbage}=\{\text{Emmy}\}.$$  In this case, each outcome is still a child, so we're dealing with events in $\Omega$, as desired. We're just partitioning into events (sets of outcomes) rather than individual outcomes.
The law of total probability says that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, $A\in\mathcal{B}$, and $(A_n)_n subset \mathcal{B}$ is a (finite or countably infinite) partition of $\Omega$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_n)>0$ for all $n$, then $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_n \mathbb{P}(A\cap A_n)=\sum_n \mathbb{P}(A|A_n)\mathbb{P}(A_n).$$
This always holds, but the partition has to be a partition of $\Omega$.

So you say that the way we partition a sample space can change P(X=k)? As I understand, when we apply the Law of Total Probability, we are essentially collecting the outcomes (and corresponding probabilities)  of an event from all the partitions and sum up to get the total number of outcomes (and probability) of the event.

No, the way we partition the sample space doesn't change the probability of the event. In this example, partitioning the sample space (where outcomes are children) is valid, partitioning a different sample space is not.
The law of total probability is not (necessarily) about partitioning the space into outcomes. It's about partitioning the space into events. Partitioning into outcomes is occasionally a special case of partitioning into events where each event is a singleton set.

Can you define the probability space of part (a) in detail?

Let $$\Omega_1={1,2,\ldots,30}\times {1},$$ $$\Omega_2={31,\ldots, 80}\times {1,2},$$ $$\Omega_3={81,\ldots, 100}\times {1,2,3},$$ and $$\Omega=\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2\cup \Omega_3.$$  Here, for $(f,k)\in \Omega$, $f$ is the family number and $k$ is the rank of a child. So each outcome is a child.
The probability of an individual outcome $(f,k)$ is $\frac{1}{100\cdot j}$ if $(f,k)\in \Omega_j$.
The set ${(3,,1)}$ is a family. It isn't an outcome. It's an event (that has only one outcome in it). ${(95,1),(95,2),(95,3)}$ is also a family. Not an outcome, but an event.

In this case, we define $$A_f={(f,1)}$$ for $f\in {1,\ldots, 30}$, $$A_f={(f,1),(f,2)}$$ for $f\in {31,\ldots, 80}$, and $$A_f={(f,1),(f,2),(f_3)}$$ for $f\in {81,\ldots, 100}$.  We use these to partition $\Omega$, where the outcomes are still individual children. We're still partitioning into families, but that's okay, because the law of total probability works for countable partitions, whether or not they are individual outcomes.

That's clear now. My very first assumption than two parts of the problem have different sample spaces (and different random variables and distributions) is also correct. In part (a) the sample space is a set of ordered pairs while in part (b) it is a set of integers, e.g., {1, ..., 190}. The only thing I couldn't understand is how you fugured out the probability of an individual outcome. You can add the definition of probability space of part (a) and compare it with part (b) if you want, to make the answer more complete for those who will read later.

Thanks. I will do it.
